# Bad redirect when translating with php using a button: <a href="?lang=en">

Tags: php, html, css, translate

I have managed to translate an example web page using an array, the problem I have found is that when pressing the button (it is used to translate) it directs you to the index, and what I want is to translate the page where you are you find.
I leave you the code in addition to some image:

```
<div class = "menu">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?> "> <? php echo $ lang ['home']?> </a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?> index.php? page = about "> <? php echo $ lang ['about']?> </a>
</li>

<? php
include ('menu.php');
?>

<li class = "right">
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?> index.php? lang = es "> <? php echo $ lang ['Spanish']?> </a>
</li>
<li class = "right">
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?> index.php? lang = ct "> <? php echo $ lang ['catalan']?> </a>
</li>
<li class = "right">
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL; ?> index.php? lang = en "> <? php echo $ lang ['english']?> </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

https://ibb.co/w62zkDM

I don't know how to do it any other way, I don't know if what I'm trying to do can be done, I have the translations in a single folder.
sorry for my english i'm using google translate.
I have also used:

but it redirects me to index anyway.
Sorry for my english i´m using google translate.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to translate the language of a page. Iam not sure how much the below solution using JS will helps.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
    } 
    .goog-gt-tt{
    display:none;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    }
    a{
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    #button{
    background:#3399ff;
    padding:5px 10px;
    box-shadow:0px 6px 16px -6px rgba(1,1,1,0.5);
    border:0;
    outline:none;
    margin:0px 10px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a onclick="changeLanguageByButtonClick('de')" id='button'>German</a>
    <a onclick="changeLanguageByButtonClick('es')" id='button'>Spanish</a>
    <a onclick="changeLanguageByButtonClick('en')" id='button'>English</a>
    <!--PAGELOADER-->
    <div id="google_translate_element" style="display:none"></div>
    <h1>Google Translator:Default Language English</h1>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
    <script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: "en"}, 'google_translate_element');
    }
    function changeLanguageByButtonClick(language) {
    var selectField = document.querySelector("#google_translate_element select");
    for(var i=0; i < selectField.children.length; i++){
    var option = selectField.children[i];
    // find desired langauge and change the former language of the hidden selection-field 
    if(option.value==language){
    selectField.selectedIndex = i;
    // trigger change event afterwards to make google-lib translate this side
    selectField.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    break;
    }
    }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I should not use the google api, I have to do it through array